# Mysql Query must also show posts without votes

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a mysql query,

i have these tables :  upload, users and ratings.

I am using the following query to get my latest posts :

```
Select All
              upload.*,
              Count(ratings.id) As totalrates,
              Avg(ratings.rating) As avgrating,
              users.nickname
            From upload
              Inner Join ratings
                On ratings.upload_id1 = upload.id
              Inner Join users
                On upload.users_id = users.id
            Group By upload.id DESC
```

However, when a post does not have any ratings yet, it won't show up, thus making it impossible to vote on :p

Does any1 know how to adjust this query or any other good suggestions on how to solve this?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select All
              upload.*,
              Count(ifnull(ratings.id,0)) As totalrates,
              Avg(ifnull(ratings.rating,0)) As avgrating,
              users.nickname
            From
              upload Inner Join
              users On upload.users_id = users.id left join
              ratings On ratings.upload_id1 = upload.id
            Group By
              upload.id DESC
```

Two changes

1. Use Left Join to join the Ratings to users and uploads
2. if ratings are not found, default to 0.

Comment: Thanks! didnt know the ifnull thingy! Working like a charm now!

Comment: Performance arguments notwithstanding, bear in mind that COALESCE is a long-established part of standard SQL. IFNULL is not (as far as I am aware).